# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when referencing div from anchor

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have three html files.

`First.html`

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#add-element-modal" data-toggle="modal" title="Add new element">Add new element</a>
```

`Second.html`

```
<div id="add-element-modal" class="element-dialog modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">
.....
.....
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="element-type">Type</label>
       <div class="controls">
            <select class="input-medium" id="element-type" onChange=displayOptionsForElementType()>
                 <option value="Text">Text</option>
                 <option value="Date">Date</option>
                 <option value="List">List</option>
            </select>
       </div>
    </div>
```

The below widget table is displayed only when we select list from above options

```
 <div class="widget widget-table " id="element-type-table-widget" style="display: none">

   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#add-element-option-modal" data-toggle="modal" title="Add Option Value">Add Option Value</a>

   .............
   .............
```

`Third.html`

```
<div id="add-element-option-modal" class="element-options-dialog modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">
 ......
 ......
</div>
```

`elements.js`

```
var displayOptionsForelementType = function() {
    var elementType = document.getElementById("element-type");
    if (elementType.options[elementType.selectedIndex].value == 'List') {
        document.getElementById("element-type-table-widget").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("element-type-table-widget").style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

This code is throwing the `Maximum Cal Stack size exceeded` error when I click on the second popup div (add-element-option-modal) by selecting list from the options in first popup

Comment: Can you post it in a fiddle?  I imagine something is triggering `displayOptionsForelementType` to be called in a loop

Comment: @Tom   Mozilla gave me the following output :

Empty String passed to getelementById()

too much recursion

Trying to create a fiddle for it

Comment: With that... My original comment still stands.

Comment: @Tom Sorry I am beginner and couldn't replicate the issue in a fiddle ..